# Is it possible to not have to restart Visual Studio Code when using it through Dropbox?

Tags: visual-studio-code, dropbox

I was wondering, is it possible to go through the following sequence and not encounter any problems?

Using Visual Studio Code through Dropbox (file inside of Dropbox) ➔ later using it on PC 2, in the same way ➔ returning to PC 1, and continuing to work on the now, presumably updated file, without running into any issues, e.g. not having to restart VSC